# Preenchimento automático de campo data na aplicação

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Tenho um formulário em minha aplicação C# ASP.Net onde preciso preencher uma data inicial e final, porém, quero padronizar para que a data final seja sempre 5 dias após a data inicial. Como fazer isso? Acredito que um Javascript resolveria, mas não tenho experiência com o mesmo.

```
<td>
    @Html.DropDownList("Nome", string.Empty)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date_Inicial)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Data_Retorno)
</td>
```

ou algo no controller como,

```
item.Data_Retorno = data_inicial.AddDays(5);
```

***Obs:*** Não sei como casar isso, se fizer no controle o que alterar na `View` ou usando um Javascript como declado na view. `Data_Retorno` deve ser preenchida automaticamente com 5 dias após a data inicial assim que ela for digitada e não deve ser possível edita-la.Como faço para ela ficar visível automaticamente? Tipo, o usuário digita a data inicial(que não necessariamente é a data atual do dia), automaticamente a data de retorno aparece no text box.

Answer (score 2):

Se `Data_Retorno` deve *sempre* ser 5 dias maior que `Date_Inicial`, calcule isso no método executado no `POST` do seu controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Index(string nome, DateTime Date_Inicial)
{
    (...)
    DateTime Data_Retorno = Date_Inicial.AddDays(5);
}
```

---

### 2014-08-29 17:59

Para exibir na view, faça:

#### Model

```
public class MinhaModel
{
    (...)
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date_Inicial { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data_Retorno { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controler

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var obj = new MinhaModel;
    (...) // O que quer que alimente a classe

    obj.Data_Retorno = obj.Date_Inicial.AddDays(5);

    return View(obj);
}
```

#### View

```
@model Model.MinhaModel

(...)

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_Inicial)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data_Retorno)
```

Comment: Certo @TiagoCésarOliveira e na view como coloco? Gostaria que ficasse visível no formulário essa data

Comment: @PFVictor editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas. Consigo através delas gravar automaticamente no banco a data de retorno como 5 dias após a data atual. E como faço para pegar a data de retorno 5 dias após a data que o usuário digitar? (não necessariamente é a data do dia) Também a data de retorno não aparece no textbox, apenas salva no banco. Como faço para ela ficar visível automaticamente? Tipo, o usuário digita a data inicial, automaticamente a data de retorno aparece no text box? @TiagoCésarOliveira

Comment: @PFVictor, por favor, edite sua pergunta com o requisito integral.

Comment: Na verdade @TiagoCésarOliveira isso já está na pergunta. Eu não disse que a data inicial é atual, e sim a data que o usuário digitar. Mas dei uma melhorada lá. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Mediante a várias alternativas segue abaixo um exemplo mediante ao envio da informação do `controller` para sua referente `view`.

**Class Model**

```
public class Professor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataInicial { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataFinal { get; set; }
}
```

**ActionResult**

```
public ActionResult Pessoas()
{
    DateTime Data = DateTime.Now;
    return View(new Professor() { Id = 0, Nome = "Nome 1", DataInicial = Data, DataFinal = Data.AddDays(5) });
}
```

**Pagina**

```
@model WebApi.Models.Professor
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Pessoas</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Professor</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataInicial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInicial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataInicial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataFinal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataFinal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataFinal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```